# How to do to use different connections in Doctrine?

Tags: transactions, doctrine, connection

I tried to use several transactions in Doctrine (v1.2.2).
Here my test:

```
// Open a new database connection
$cnx1 = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mydsn'); // $cnx1 will be named '0'

// Open a second database connection
$cnx2 = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mydsn'); // $cnx2 will be named '1'

// Start a transaction on connection #1
$cnx1->beginTransaction();
// Update the name of user #1
$query1 = $cnx1->createQuery();
$query1->update('SfGuardUser')->set("username", "'Name 1'")->where("id='1'");
$query1->execute();

// Start an other transaction on connection #2
$cnx2->beginTransaction();
// Update the name of user #2
$query2 = $cnx2->createQuery();
$query2->update('SfGuardUser')->set("username", "'Name 2'")->where("id='2'");
$query2->execute();

// Commit transaction #2
$cnx2->commit();
```

(The default isolation level is REPEATABLE READ.)

After running the code, both user names have changed in the database.
According to me, only the name of user #2 should be modified, as the transaction #1 has not yet been committed.

When debugging, I saw that it is always the connection #2 (the last opened) which is used for all queries. Why ?

In the Doctrine documentation, we can read "From the start Doctrine has been designed to work with multiple connections. Unless separately specified Doctrine always uses the current connection for executing the queries."

How to do to use different connections and uniques transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Doctrine (still there in the current 1.2 release, as far as I can tell).  When you create a query from Doctrine_Connection::createQuery(), it does not pass itself to the query as the first parameter, so it is always created on the default connection.

The bugfix should be a simple one, passing in $this to Doctrine_Query::create() in Doctrine_Connection.

A workaround is to create the query yourself, and pass in the connection:

```
$query1 = Doctrine_Query::create($cnx1);
$query2 = Doctrine_Query::create($cnx2);
```

Comment: fix and fork of doctrine 1 of mishal here: https://github.com/mishal/doctrine1/commit/fe3319a43c8e589fd63d22ca8d48286aee3634f1